# "View more tables" option doesn't work in web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I can see Google add button for datasets with many tables in it and this button simply doesn't work for me. You can click on it but nothing happens.

Is it a Bug ?

How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post and also restructured it.  And I have removed thanks, you say thanks by up voting any good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This button will show details for the entire dataset in the main view on the right, which includes a table list that scales to a larger number of tables.

Mikhail is correct in that a maximum of 100 tables per dataset are shown in the left nav now, but the table list in the dataset view should be capable of showing somewhere around 10000 per dataset.

We're aware this situation isn't ideal, as we've increased the number of clicks it takes to get to certain tables within a dataset.  We hope to improve this soon.

Comment: Thank you Danny for clarifying things. As I mentioned I have tested it with 8K tables and all tables were shown in main dataset view (as it is less than 10K) so I would expect to not to even see this button - but it is still presented in navigation bar. just sharing ...

Comment: Hi Danny, we have some issues with this button at the moment. About 100 tables are shown in the left nav, then the "view more tables" button. However, when I click on "view more tables", I don't see a list of the rest of the tables in the main view, just the main heading "Dataset Details" and two subheadings "Description" and "Tables" -- but no info about the tables. An extra click to see the tables would be fine, but no tables at all is frustrating. Do you have any idea how long it is likely to take for this issue to be fixed?

Comment: Yes, as rebeccaroisin mentioned, it just doesn't work - I have tables after FAST_LAP table but can't access it

Comment: Thanks for the additional info - this is a second bug here that we're also working to resolve.

Comment: The issue where multiple aggregate tables in the same dataset would cause the dataset's table list to appear empty should now be fixed.

Comment: Thank you Danny. I can confirm this. it behaves now as I would expected from where it goes

Answer (score 1):

From my recent experience with GBQ UI - Google Team is constantly working on improving their current (quite weak) UI. I can confirm that this button doesn't work as of right now for me too. and i dont see yet what it supposed to do. My best guess is it should show more tables in the tables list on the right (dataset details) panel. But it already shows quite a lot of them. The max size of dataset I have is ~8K tables and they all enlisted here. But withing the navigation panel  - only 100 (or so) are shown with that button below them and it does nothing so far, but (indirectly) broke filtering functionality in BigQuery Mate that I am going to fix shortly.

Comment: For those using or interested in BigQuery Mate - i have just puiblished fixed version to address recent (yesterday's) changes in GBQ UI. Please update your extension to get it work. Let me know if you still see something broken. As Google Team works non-stop on improving BQ UI (thank yo guys!!) - i am expecting such brokeage of my extension to happen again and again  - but I will try to keep it alive :o)

Comment: Thank you, Mickhail, I will definitely try your extension. But the problem is that I have tables after FAST_LAP but I can't access it right now.

Comment: I really feel your pain as I also see those things quite broken, confusing and not working for me. Looks like the best direction is to leave this new feature alone till it will be fixed,done,completed by Google Team. :o(

Answer (score 1):

I see the pattern of how it is broken: those datasets which have only "straight" list of tables or have just ONLY one group of groupped tables are working fine - they properly being showed in Dataset Browser (panel on the right to the nav bar). For those which have multiple groups (like in your example above) it is totally broken (in my cases - it is just totally empty!
Honestly, I am surprised to see such oopses in such product!
Usually, when you know what exactly broken  - it makes you feel better and/or you can plan for workarouond if needed - so that's why I am posting my findings as a separate answer

> Update:

Looks like last week Google Team pushed great batch of UI improvements: Nab Bar resize control was the most visible one! Among others - enriched Recent and Saved Query Panels. Those are now source for overall slowness especially during resizing or for Query Editor to appear (in case if you have long list of queries in those lists). So far my recommendation (till it will be fixed by Google if they will treat this as something to be fixed) is to avoid having those on your page unless it is what you need to work with.

As usually, when UI is redesigned, a lot of BigQuery Mate functionality was broken (as all page structure was quite changed).
As of now, I fixed all and you can find most recent fixed version in Chrome Store.
Let me know if some Mate features still fail to work as expected

Comment: Thank you for the additional report - this is a separate bug we will look into fixing soon.

Comment: The issue where multiple aggregate tables in the same dataset would cause the dataset's table list to appear empty should now be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to google team, this bug is solved right now